# fopen filename starts with weird dot

Tags: c, file, fopen

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TmGr.png]

Hi.

As you may see I'm trying to save recent data from a C project inside a log file where the files name corresponds to the actual time/date.

While the path is combined and displayed correctly inside the console the file itself starts with a weird dot, to be more precise a blank space followed by that dot and another blank space, displayed in the picture.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit and cygwin64.

The relevant bits of code are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
void save_to_file(char* timestamp, char* homepath, int generation)
char* create_timestamp(char* timestamp)
int main(){
    char homepath[28] = "D:\\cygwin64\\home\\ignite\\log\\";
    int generation = 0;

    char* timestamp = malloc (30 * sizeof(char));
    create_timestamp(timestamp);
    save_to_file(timestamp, homepath, generation);
}

void save_to_file(char* timestamp, char* homepath, int generation){
    char string[4];
    char logchar[4] = "log";
    char dot[] = {"."};
    char fileend[5] = {".txt"};
    char* path = malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(path, homepath);
    strcat(path, logchar);
    snprintf(string, 4, "%d", generation);
    strcat(path, string);
    strcat(path, dot);
    strcat(path, timestamp);
    strcat(path, fileend);
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "ab+");
    if(f == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        //write to file
    }
}
char* create_timestamp(char* timestamp){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *info;
    char buffer[30], *string, *work;
    string = malloc (5* sizeof(char));
    work = malloc (30* sizeof(char));
    char point[] = {"."};
    time( &rawtime );

    info = localtime( &rawtime );
    strcpy(buffer, asctime(info));

    int n = info->tm_mday;
    snprintf(string, 4, "%d", n);
    strcpy(work, string);

    n = (int) info->tm_mon + 1;
    snprintf(string, 3, "%d", n);
    strcat(work, point);
    strcat(work, string);
    ///*
    n = info->tm_year + 1900;
    snprintf(string, 5, "%d", n);
    strcat(work, point);
    strcat(work, string);


    n = info->tm_hour;
    snprintf(string, 3, "%d", n);
    strcat(work, point);
    strcat(work, string);

    n = info->tm_min;
    snprintf(string, 3, "%d", n);
    strcat(work, point);
    strcat(work, string);

    n = info->tm_sec;
    snprintf(string, 3, "%d", n);
    strcat(work, point);
    strcat(work, string);
    strcpy(timestamp, work);
    free(string);
    return timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Show us how do you get `homepath`?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?  And as noted, what you are showing is not _all_ of the relevant code.  Include enough so that whats provided can compile.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code uses several variables (for instance, `homepath`, `generation`, `timestamp`) you've not defined that are all used in that block of code. Your code should contain a complete example that, if needed, we can copy/paste and compile.

Comment: Because you are using the `"ab+"` option in `fopen()`, is it reasonable to expect that the file you are opening is pre-existing, (i.e. and could include  _a blank space followed by that dot and another blank space_)?

Comment: for testing purpose, print the `homepath` string - see if the unnecessary dot is from there.

Comment: I was using "w" mode before and tried "ab+" afterwards, read that somewhere else..
The suggested print of path results in an correct path as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I think the code i now complete enough to be compilable..

Comment: Why do you keep reverting my edit?

Comment: Your array is too short. `"D:\\cygwin64\\home\\ignite\\log\\"` is 29 bytes.

Comment: Why the sprintf followed by tons of strcat? Use `snprintf(path, 60, "%d.%s.txt", generation, timestamp);`

Comment: Wow that was it...
Counted for single \ but added \\ later on, still don't get why this produces a dot like that.

Comment: @Tignite because there is no `'\0'` at the end, `strcpy` has Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score -2):

> Your array is too short. "D:\cygwin64\home\ignite\log\" is 29 bytes. – melpomene

Comment: I am not the down voter, but it appears your intent is to credit the poster of this comment by listing it as an answer.  An upclick of the comment (under your original post) is acceptable for that purpose.  Or, you can ask the commenter to post their comment as an answer so you can upclick or accept.

Comment: Please don't repost someone else's comment as an answer without first asking them to do it. If they don't respond, or tell you that you can, feel free to post your own answer, but make it more than just a straight quote of the comment -- explain why it matters, what the effects are, and so on.

Comment: Well I didn't find a way to mark his solution as an answer so I decided to quote him so it's obvious that the problem is fixed...
@QPaysTaxes instead of just complaining you could have given useful instructions to a newbie like ryyker did. "Please don't repost" isn't helping at all.
Btw I as well can't find the option to upvote comments, I only can see the counter and/or vote the OP and the given answer?!

Comment: @Tignite ...First, [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Passive aggression is not nice. Yes, you were being passive aggressive. Secondly, I did; could you please re-read my comment? The only thing rykker mentioned that I didn't was upvoting the comment, which is less useful than getting the original commenter to post an answer, since the system considers the question unanswered.